# Pseudo-morphisms in essentially algebraic theories

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, algebraic-theory

Categories with terminal objects can be written as an essentially algebraic theory or a generalized algebraic theory: There is one sort $M$ with unary operations $\DeclareMathOperator\dom{dom}\dom$, $\DeclareMathOperator\cod{cod}\cod$ and $!$, a binary operation $\circ$ and a nullary operation $1$.
There is an automatically derived notion of homomorphisms between these algebras, which when worked out produces functors *strictly* preserving the terminal object.
However, we know that the most natural notion to investigate is functors $F$ such that $F(1) \dashrightarrow 1$ is an isomorphism.

Is there a way to systematically derive a notion of "weak" homomorphisms of EAT/GAT algebras, such that when applied to categories or even bicategories, produces the "correct" notion of functors? I would imagine it to be easier using generalized algebraic theories, since objects now appear in the sorts. Is there anything in the literature discussing this?

Comment: For categories with terminal objects and similar, this is the sort of thing that 2-monads and 2-dimensional universal algebra is designed to handle